# React Quill disappears on rerender

Tags: reactjs, text-editor, react-quill

I'm working on creating a text editor that handle image uploads, everything works fine but when it re renders it completely disappears

I tried using useMemo on modules and also add a unqiue key to  but nothing seemed to work.
if im removing the image handler from my modules then it stops disappearing.

Can anyone please guide, what the error is?

```
const uploadToCloudinary = async (file: File): Promise<string> => {
  //code for uploading
  return url;
};

export interface EditorProps {
  description: string;
  setDescription: (description: string) => void;
}

export default function QuillEditor({
  description,
  setDescription,
}: EditorProps) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(description || "");
  const [qid, setId] = useState<string>("");
  const reactQuillRef = useRef<ReactQuill>(null);

  const onChange = (content: string) => {
    setValue(content);
    console.log(content);
    setDescription(content);
  };

  const imageHandler = useCallback(() => {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "file");
    input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
    input.click();
    input.onchange = async () => {
      if (input !== null && input.files !== null) {
        const file = input.files[0];
        const url = await uploadToCloudinary(file);
        const quill = reactQuillRef.current;
        if (quill) {
          const range = quill.getEditorSelection();
          range && quill.getEditor().insertEmbed(range.index, "image", url);
        }
      }
    };
  }, []);
  const modules = {
    toolbar: {
      container: [
        [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
        ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
        [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
        ["link", "image"],
        ["code-block"],
        [
          {
            color: [
              "#000000", ...
            ],
          },
          {
            background: [
              "#000000", ...
            ],
          },
        ],
        ["clean"],
      ],
      handlers: {
        image: imageHandler,
      },
    },
    clipboard: {
      matchVisual: false,
    },
  };

  return (
    <ReactQuill
      ref={reactQuillRef}
      theme="snow"
      placeholder="Start writing..."
      modules={modules}
      formats={[
        "header", ...
      ]}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      style={{ height: "350px", overflowY: "auto" }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `modules` object is recreated/re-defined whenever the component rerenders. Just memoize the object with `useMemo`:

```
  const modules = useMemo(() => (
//your object here
), [imageHandler]);
```

Comment: as I have mentioned, I have already tried this, it did not work. What I noticed was it doesn't disappear on normal render but if I make any changes in the modules array it completely disappears from the DOM, any idea whys that happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same implementation with the only difference being that my imageHandler function does not use useCallback and is instead just an async function. I haven't encountered this problem so I think you should try that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the rerender, but I extracted modules to a variable and used useMemo on it, but the dependency array I left empty because the problem kept coming back, now everything works as I expect.

```
 const modules = useMemo(
        () => ({
            toolbar: {
                container: [
                    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
                    [{ header: 1 }, { header: 2 }],
                    [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
                    [{ script: 'sub' }, { script: 'super' }],
                    [{ direction: 'rtl' }],
                    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
                    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
                    [{ font: [] }],
                    [
                        {
                            size: fontSizeArray,
                        },
                    ],
                    [{ align: [] }],
                    ['link', 'image'],
                    ['loacalImage'],
                    ['socialLink'],
                ],
                handlers: {
                    loacalImage: openElfinder,
                    socialLink: handleOpenModal,
                },
            },
        }),
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        []
    );
```